# Can an x86 based OS use an x86-64 processor in protected mode and use PAE?

Tags: x86, operating-system, x86-64, hardware

I was interested in operating systems that used segmentation from 32 bit protected mode processors. When AMD added long mode, they didn't the segmentation hardware protection to it. Can any x86-64 processor in 32 bit protected mode use Physical Address extension so it can address more than 4 GB of memory?

Comment: Yes, but it's painful to only have 4GiB of virtual address space while having much more physical address space.  (With only 1 or 2 GiB of that reserved for the kernel.)  Segmentation doesn't help.  See Linus Torvalds' comments about PAE (https://cl4ssic4l.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/linus-torvalds-about-pae/).  An x86-64 in legacy mode like you describe is *exactly* like a 32-bit-only CPU with PAE, that's how x86-64 CPUs could run existing OSes when they were first released.

Comment: In 64 bit long mode there's no support for the hardware protection modes that 32 bit protected mode offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can any x86-64 processor in 32 bit protected mode use Physical Address extension so it can address more than 4 GB of memory?

Yes.

Such an OS would be able to use more than the 64 GiB of memory (physical address space) that PAE was originally limited to; and could also still use segmentation and virtual8086 mode.

Unfortunately, 32-bit code can't use the extra registers that were added, which (depending on software) probably means up to 20% performance loss in most software (compared to 64-bit software on the same CPU).